# How to monitor concurrent users execution for each thread group in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

How to monitor concurrent users execution for  thread group in JMeter

For Example:
ThreadGroup1 : 100 concurrent users
ThreadGroup2:  500 concurrent users
ThreadGroup3:  600 concurrent users.
Is there any way to check if above concurrent users are used for each threadGroup in any graph post test execution or during test execution in JMeter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener seems to be what you're looking for

[image]

The listener can be installed as a part of **3 Basic Graphs** bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for your inputs.  I will be executing tests from command line over distributed environment(Master & Slave). Output file is *.jtl file. Can we get this report if we load jtl in JMeter GUI instance.  Also, is it a best practice to include listener in remote load test execution ? Please share your thoughts

Comment: 1. It is possible to open .jtl file in the Active Threads Over Time listener when your test ends, just locate it using "Browse" button and the charts will be rendered from the results. 2. It is possible to generate a .png image with the chart out of the .jtl results file using [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line) like `JMeterPluginsCMD --generate-png activethreads.png --input-jtl result.jtl --plugin-type ThreadsStateOverTime`

Answer (score 0):

you can add different listeners whatever you want for your case .

> -> Right click on your thread Group.
> -> go to Add -> Listener
> -> {View Results Tree ,Summary Report ,Graph Results, jp@gv-Hits per second , Active Threads over time and many    more listeners }.

let me know if you want know more !